# .Net CORE Dapper Connection String?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am setting up my first .NET Core application.   I am going to user Dapper (1.50.0-rc2) for the ORM.

I have added the following to my *appsettings.json* file.

```
"Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
        "ConnectionString": "user id=exampleusername;password=examplepassword;Data Source=db.example.com;Database=exampledb;"
    }
},
```

I am confused at how to get the value of *ConnectionString*.   As .NET Core is so new, online examples are all over the place and none seem to actually cover this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a sample Console App for .NET core on my GitHub [repository](https://github.com/dopare/URF.NET/blob/master/samples/ConsoleAppEF7/Program.cs#L30)

Setup phase

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
```

Build phase

`Configuration = builder.Build();`

Use phase

`Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")`

You can use this value for `Dapper`

P.S.

You need to add 3 dependencies into your `project.json`

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
```

**UPDATED**

Specific solution

make Configuration static property and **add private setter**

`public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }`

and change your extension

```
namespace GamesCore.Extensions 
{
    public class ScoreExtensions 
    { 
        private static string dataConnectionString = Startup.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"); 
    } 
}
```

For .NET Core 2.0 everything is same and only project file is changed so you need to use following packages:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I have "Setup phase" and "Build phase" in the Startup method of the Startup.cs (they were already there from the Visual Studio template).   I added the missing dependencies to my project.json.   But on the "Use phase" I get 'The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context'   I tried adding a using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration but that results in 'The type or namespace name 'GetConnectionString' does not exist' error.

Comment: Sorry, hit the enter key too quickly.   See updated comment above.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code where are you trying to use the `Configuration` ?

Comment: In an an extension class;

```namespace GamesCore.Extensions
{
 public class ScoreExtensions
    {

  private static string dataConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
  

  
 }
}```

Comment: How about .net core 2?

Comment: @niico added packages for .net core 2

Answer (score 7):

My walkthrough:

1. Add **ConnectionStrings** section in **appsettings.json**:

   ```cs
   "ConnectionStrings": {
      "cs1": "Server=xxxx;Port=xxxx;Database=xxxx; User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Pooling=false;",
      "cs2": "Server=xxxx;Port=xxxx;Database=xxxx; User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Pooling=false;",
      "cs3": "Server=xxxx;Port=xxxx;Database=xxxx; User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Pooling=false;"
   },
   ```
2. Create class that represents the connection strings section:

   ```cs
   public class ConnectionStringList
   {
       public string cs1 { get; set; }
       public string cs2 { get; set; }
       public string cs3 { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Open **Startup.cs** and add the above configuration class to the services collection in ConfigureServices:

   ```cs
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       ...
       services.AddOptions();
       services.Configure<ConnectionStringList>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
   }
   ```
4. Inject **IOptions<ConnectionStringList>** into your controller/service etc. and retreive your connection string value from **Value** property:

   ```cs
   public SampleController(IOptions<ConnectionStringList> connectionStrings)
   {
       string cs1 = connectionStrings.Value.cs1;
       ...
   ```