# Net Core Connection String Dapper visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, dapper

I am trying to get a Connection String set up in my .Net Core application but i keep getting the error:

*System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'*

I have tried adding the following to *appsettings.json*:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {

"Analysis": "Server=DESKTOP-MYSERVER;Database=MYDATABASE;User Id=sa; Password=Password123;Provider=System.Data.SqlClient;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Pooling=false;"
}
```

I also tried using web.config like I used to before .Net Core:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Analysis" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-MYSERVER;Database=MYDATABASE;User Id=sm;Password=Password123;"/>
```

Then in c# i have:

```
public List<DapperTest> ReadAll()
    {
        var data = new List<DapperTest>();
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Analysis"].ConnectionString))
        {
             data = db.Query<DapperTest>("select * from testTable").ToList();
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Both ways give me the exception of:

*System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'*

I have used the following resources:

[.Net CORE Dapper Connection String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597300/net-core-dapper-connection-string)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro

[Get connection string from App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536715/get-connection-string-from-app-config)

But I am missing something. I have only set up connection strings once and it was not in .Net Core so it could be obvious to others.

Comment: which line are you getting error ? What object is `NULL` ?

Comment: .NET core does configuration differently.  Do you have an `appsettings.json` ?  The recommended way is to load the appsettings into your `IConfigurationRoot` object and inject that into your class, and get the connection string from there

Comment: @Shyju I am getting the object is null on the following line in the c# code:  `using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Analysis"].ConnectionString))`

Comment: @Jonesopolis I did try to add the connection string to appsettings.json as shown in my code above. I have not yet tried to load it via `IConfigurationRoot `

Comment: @Jonesopolis would I want to use the [Options Pattern](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/) for this?

Comment: Is this for .net core 1 or 2?

Comment: i have it running with .net core 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using appsettings.json, create a simple POCO class to model your connection string configurations like this:

```
public class ConnectionConfig
{
        public string Analysis {get;set;}
}
```

Add this line in ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<ConnectionConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
```

Data service class

```
class YourClass{
    private string _connectionString;

    YourClass(string connectionString){
       _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    //Your implementation
    public List<DapperTest> ReadAll()
    {
        var data = new List<DapperTest>();
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)
        {
            data = db.Query<DapperTest>("select * from testTable").ToList();
        }

       return data;
   }
}
```

Inject `IOptions<ConnectionConfig>` in your controller constructor .

```
class YourController : Controller{
   YourClass _testing;

   YourController(IOptions<ConnectionConfig> connectionConfig){
       var connection = connectionConfig.Value;
       string connectionString = connection.Analysis;
       _testing = new YourClass(connectionString );
    }
   public IActionResult Index() { 
        var testingData = _testing.ReadAll(); 
        return View(); 
     }
 }
```

Comment: This is a huge help. One simple follow up question though: how would I pass in a argument now when calling this in a controller (specifically what type because I am unfamiliar with  `IOptions`)? For example what would I pass in as argument here:                                                    `public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var testing = new YourClass();
            var testingData = testing.ReadAll();

            return View();
        }`

Comment: You can also inject IOptions in your controller's constructor and do the same like I did for YourClass

Comment: Now added controller implementation of IOptions

Comment: I am working at it now and With your implementation I am still running into the error: "Cannot convert from 'string' to IOptions<ConnectionConfig>" right here: `_testing = new DataBaseData(connectionString)`

Comment: Are you sure adding this line, `string connectionString = connection.Analysis;` ? Show me your implementations. it is hard to get the error from the above piece

Comment: Yes I have that line added

Comment: I got it, it looks like i had this line wrong ` YourClass(string connectionString){
       _connectionString = connectionString;
    } ` in `YourClass` I had it taking a  `IOptions` for a type. Thank you very much for your help sir. This is the clearest solution I could have been given!

Comment: Does this apply to .net core 2 and above?