# Setup Oracle DataSources & Connection String In AppSetting.json file in .net core 2.1

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to setup oracle database settings in `appsetting.json` file in my .netcore
application
**my previous datasource structur like this in Asp.Net**

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="Test" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=180.148.11.140)(PORT=1221))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl))) "/>
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
      connectionString="User Id=Emp;Password=abc@123;Data Source=Emp"/>

  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store / Retrieve ConnectionString from appSettings.json in ASP.net Core 2 MVC app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507382/store-retrieve-connectionstring-from-appsettings-json-in-asp-net-core-2-mvc-ap)

Comment: I want to handle **dataSource** provided inside `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` i all ready know how to get  `<connectionStrings>` and access to dbcontaxt or other pages please try to understand my promble.@PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Those are just tags. Create the *same* sections in the JSON file and read them just like any other setting. There are no special paths or tags in .NET Core. Perhaps you wanted to ask something different, like how to have the Oracle client configure itself from those settings?

Comment: ok than how i handle  <version **number="*"**> this tag in json file?

Comment: That's a JSON question, not related to settings. You specify it the same way as any other object in JSON - as a dictionary whose keys are the property names, values are the property contents. Eg: `"version" : { "number" : "*"} ,...`. You *don't* have to follow the same structure though. Create a configuration class in the shape you want and write the JSON text in a way that matches it. An `OracleSettings` class with a Version, Alias and Descriptor string properties would be enough. That maps easily to an `"OracleSettings": { Version=*", Alias="Test", Descriptor="...."}`

Comment: thanks i will try its...

Comment: did you got this working using the appsettings.config?