# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API - ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I am new to ASP.net Core web api.

I am trying to read connection strings using `ConfigurationManager`

```
var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainDB"].ConnectionString;
```

But it throws `NullReferenceException`

```
System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get returned null.
```

I have a connection string in my web.config file.

```
   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MainDB" connectionString="Data Source=XXXXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Note**: This is ASP.Net Core 2.1 WebAPI.

Comment: aren't you using appsettings.json

Comment: Thank you for point it out. I am new to core, and didn't know it works differently here. thanks.

Comment: i think in asp.net core dependency injection is inbuilt. You need to go by way of dependency injection. you can get your answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507382/store-retrieve-connectionstring-from-appsettings-json-in-asp-net-core-2-mvc-ap

Comment: that link has an explained answer I think you will get your point clear from there